# Query with laravel

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8

I am learning laravel and I have some doubts. In my project I use two models: Teacher and Course with a HasMany relationship between them. I would like to have an endpoint which gives me the information of every teacher with his courses.

```
    public function get_teachers_courses()
    {   
        $profesor= 'Profesor';
        $teachers = Teacher::with('courses')->whereIs_active(true)->get();

        return $teachers->map(function ($teacher) use ($profesor){

            return [
                'id'=> $teacher->id,
                'name'=> $profesor. ' '. $teacher->name,
                'courses'=> $teacher->courses,
            ];
        });
    }
```

This is the teacher's model

```
class Teacher extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

     /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'is_active' => 'boolean',
    ];

     //Relationship with courses
     public function courses(){
        return $this->hasMany(Course::class, 'teacher_id');
    }
}
```

I have done this and it works but I would like to know if it is the best option in terms of performance queries. My intention was to eager load the relationship using Teacher::with('courses') to avoid n+1 queries. I would appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you have is pretty performant, you could clean up your code a little if you wished to. Below is how I would do it personally, which also avoids the need to `map()`.

#### Teacher Migration

```php
Schema::create('teachers', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    // You shouldn't need to cast this in the model
    $table->boolean('active')->default(0);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

#### Course Migration

```php
Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->bigInteger('teacher_id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

#### Teacher Model

```php
class Teacher extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    // No need for the boolean cast

    protected $appends = [
        // Always appends $teacher->formal_name to eloquent queries
        'formal_name'
    ];

    public function courses(){
        // You do not need to include 'teacher_id' below
        // as it is already named using common Laravel convention
        return $this->hasMany(Course::class);
    }

    public function getFormalNameAttribute() {
        // Can be accessed via $teacher->formal_name
        return 'Professor '.$this->name;
    }
}
```

#### Course Model

```php
class Course extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function teacher(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Teacher::class);
    }
}
```

#### Eloquent Query & Result

Because you have added `formal_name` to `$appends` in the `Teacher` model, it will be automatically appended whenever you query `$teachers` or `$course->teacher` etc - as you can see by `+formal_name` at the bottom of each `Teacher` model instance below.

```php
$teachers = Teacher::where('active', true)->with(['courses'])->get();
return $teachers;
```

```php
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1290
  all: [
    App\Models\Teacher {#2240
      id: 1,
      name: "Lex Breann",
      active: 1,
      created_at: null,
      updated_at: null,
      courses: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2248
        all: [
          App\Models\Course {#2253
            id: 1,
            teacher_id: 1,
            name: "Advanced Laravel",
            created_at: null,
            updated_at: null,
          },
          App\Models\Course {#2254
            id: 2,
            teacher_id: 1,
            name: "Tailwind Starter Course",
            created_at: null,
            updated_at: null,
          },
          App\Models\Course {#2255
            id: 3,
            teacher_id: 1,
            name: "Beginning React",
            created_at: null,
            updated_at: null,
          },
        ],
      },
      +formal_name: "Professor Lex Breann",
    },
    App\Models\Teacher {#2241
      id: 2,
      name: "Angelia Chile",
      active: 1,
      created_at: null,
      updated_at: null,
      courses: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2237
        all: [
          App\Models\Course {#2256
            id: 4,
            teacher_id: 2,
            name: "Managing Web Servers",
            created_at: null,
            updated_at: null,
          },
          App\Models\Course {#2257
            id: 5,
            teacher_id: 2,
            name: "Eloquent Essentials",
            created_at: null,
            updated_at: null,
          },
        ],
      },
      +formal_name: "Professor Angelia Chile",
    },
  ],
}
```

#### Query Active Courses

If you wanted to add an `active` col to Courses too, you could also do something like this in the `Teacher` model.

Of course, you could add `->where('active', true)` to the `courses()` relation if you wanted to, but I assume you would be using that relation in some kind of admin control panel (where you would want to see inactive courses too).

```php
// Teacher.php
public function active_courses(){
    return $this->hasMany(Course::class)->where('active', true);
}
```

```php
$teacher = Teacher::find(1);
$teacher->active_courses;
```

```php
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2239
  all: [
    App\Models\Course {#2238
      id: 1,
      teacher_id: 1,
      active: 1,
      name: "Advanced Laravel",
      created_at: null,
      updated_at: null,
    },
  ],
}
```